# Counting occurrences of values of string variable using collapse

Tags: string, count, aggregate, stata

In a dataset like the one below,

```
clear
input patid str2 dx 
1   qw
1   qe
1   qw
2   qw
2   qw
2   qs
2   qs
3   qe
3   qe
3   qs
3   qw
3   qw
3   qw
3   qs
4   qe
5   qa
5   qs
5   qw
5   qe
5   qw
end
```

I've found that I can count occurrences of each value of the string variable `dx` using subscripts[1], or if I convert `dx` to a numeric label if using `collapse`[2].

Is there a command or syntax where I can count occurrences directly (without conversion etc.) from the string variable itself when using `collapse`?

e.g. if I tried `collapse (count) countdx=dx, by(patid dx)`, this returns the error message `variable dx not found`.

(of course, this shouldn't work: and when I tried `collapse (count) countdx=dx, by(patid)`, this returns the error `type mismatch`)

Notes:

[1]

```
by patid dx, sort: egen ndx = count(dx)
by patid dx: g orderdx=_n
by patid dx: drop if orderdx>1
```

[2]

```
g numdx=.
replace numdx=1 if dx=="qa"
replace numdx=2 if dx=="qe"
replace numdx=3 if dx=="qs"
replace numdx=4 if dx=="qw"
collapse (count)  countdx=numdx, by(patid dx)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your examples, but not your question, all imply that you want to count separately for each distinct value of an identifier `patid`.

```
clear
input patid str2 dx 
1   qw
1   qe
1   qw
2   qw
2   qw
2   qs
2   qs
3   qe
3   qe
3   qs
3   qw
3   qw
3   qw
3   qs
4   qe
5   qa
5   qs
5   qw
5   qe
5   qw
end

bysort patid dx : gen count = _N 

tabdisp patid dx , c(count) 

----------------------------------
          |           dx          
    patid |   qa    qe    qs    qw
----------+-----------------------
        1 |          1           2
        2 |                2     2
        3 |          2     2     3
        4 |          1            
        5 |    1     1     1     2
----------------------------------
```

For a review of technique in this territory, see [this paper](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0042). Searching [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/) for mentions of `dm0042` will find very many related examples.

For problems of even moderate size, `tabdisp` won't be especially practical. It is mentioned here to show directly what the previous command does.

Extending this to `collapse`,  one simple device is

```
gen one = 1

collapse (sum) one, by(patid dx)
```

although I should mention that `contract` was written more explicitly for this purpose (cf. discussion of its precursor in Cox 1998).

On the other hand, if you did create the `count` variable, then

```
collapse (mean) count, by(patid dx)
```

would have precisely the same effect.

Cox, N.J. 1998. Collapsing datasets to frequencies. *Stata Technical Bulletin* 44: 2-3. [.pdf here](http://www.stata-press.com/journals/stbcontents/stb44.pdf)